# Create a Javascript array from an array formatted string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm getting a string (which has array markup) from a CMS but it is not being recognized as an array by javascript

```
// Example of how data comes from CMS
var data = [ ["<div class='example'><h2>University</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>", 13.3851, -2.2568, "/example.png"],       
["<div class='example2'><h2>University Two</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum Example</p></div>", -3.3851, -22.2568, "/examplenow.png"], ] ;

// where I need data as array
googlelocations = data;
```

when I log data I get:

```
0: "[\"<div class='example'><h2>University</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>\", -3.3851, -22.2568, \"/example.png\"],\r\n[\"<div class='example2'><h2>University Two</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum Example</p></div>\", -3.3851, -22.2568, \"/examplenow.png\"],"
```

​
length: 1
How do I get the var data to be an array of the above info?

Comment: should there be a parent array bracket? you current have something like this: `var data = ['', ''], ['', ''],`

Comment: Show the **exact** string that comes from the server.

Comment: It looks like you're just missing `[` at the start, and `]` at the end. But the whole process seems strange. How exactly is the CMS generating this string if not as JSON ?

Comment: Do you need all that HTML data? Or do you just need the Lat/Long numbers? If you just need some bit and pieces of data from the incoming array it might be a good idea to pull the out info you need, a regex would probably be the easiest way to do that, and place it into a new array.

Comment: Oh, and as duxfox and @DenysSéguret pointed out, you probably need to place each array you're being returning into a parent array, creating a multidimensional array of sorts.

Comment: Yes, your data should be like - var data = `[["<div class='example'><h2>University</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>", 13.3851, -2.2568, "/example.png"],       
["<div class='example2'><h2>University Two</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum Example</p></div>", -3.3851, -22.2568, "/examplenow.png"]]`;.   And to get array you can parse it using JSON.parse(data)

Comment: @AbhaySehgal That's not JSON. You would just flatten the arrays.

Comment: I added brackets and showed the console log, it looks like syntax may be getting escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting

```
["<div class='example'><h2>University</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>", 13.3851, -2.2568, "/example.png"],       
["<div class='example2'><h2>University Two</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum Example</p></div>", -3.3851, -22.2568, "/examplenow.png"],
```

from the CMS as something like @DATA.

You need to wrap these Arrays into an Array of Arrays in order for them to be properly assigned into the `data` variable.

`var data = [ @DATA ];`

Comment: What does the "@" do?

Comment: @ will do Nothing, he just giving variable name as @DATA I think

Comment: @steve The data just gets crammed into a single array child, not separated.

Comment: @Sam as other user said,  you should paste the exact string that comes from the server.

Comment: that var data is accurate/

Answer (score 0):

To parse that response, that seems to be an array, you could use `JSON.parse()`, in such a case you need to build a valid array or js object. In this case adding `[` `]` solves the issue, but it depends on how is exactly the response.

```js
var data = "[\"<div class='example'><h2>University</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>\", -3.3851, -22.2568, \"/example.png\"],\r\n[\"<div class='example2'><h2>University Two</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum Example</p></div>\", -3.3851, -22.2568, \"/examplenow.png\"]"

data = JSON.parse("["+data+"]")

console.log(data)
```

If you want just the values, you could do instead, something like:

```js
var data = "[\"<div class='example'><h2>University</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>\", -3.3851, -22.2568, \"/example.png\"],\r\n[\"<div class='example2'><h2>University Two</h2><hr><p>Lorem Ipsum Example</p></div>\", -3.3851, -22.2568, \"/examplenow.png\"]"

data = data.split(",")

var latLong = [data[1],data[2],data[5],data[6]] 

console.log(latLong)
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @Sam Do you need the values? or the whole thing? and the response have that 0: in the beginning? Because if you need the values, see the second example.